# Maintaining auto ranking as a column in MongoDB

Tags: sql, mongodb, database

I am using MongoDB as my database.

I have data which contains rank and name as columns. Now a new row can be updated with a rank different from ranks already existing or can be same.

If same then the ranks of other rows must be adjusted .

Rows having lesser rank than the to be inserted one must be incremented by one and the rows which are having ranks can remain as it it.

Feature is something like number bulleted list in MS Word type of applications. Where inserting a row in between adjust the numbering of other rows below it.

Rank 1 is the highest rank.

For e.g. there are 3 rows

```
Name  Rank
A       1
B       2
C       3
```

Now i want to update a row with D as name and 2 as rank. So  now after the row insert, the DB should like below

```
Name  Rank
A       1
B       3
C       4
D       2
```

Probably using Database triggers i can achieve this by updating the other rows.

I have couple of questions

(a) Is there any other better way than using database trigger for achieving this kind of scenario ? Updating all the rows might be a time consuming job.

(b) Does MongoDB support database trigger natively ?

Best Regards,

Saurav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, MongoDB, does not provide triggers (yet). Also I don't think trigger is really a great way to achieve this.

So I would just like to throw some ideas, see if it makes sense.

**Approach 1**

Maybe instead of *disturbing* those many documents, you can create a collection with only one document (Let's call the collection ranking). In that document, have an array field call ranks. Since it's an array it's already maintaining a sequence.

```
{
 _id : "RANK",
 "ranks" : ["A","B","C"]
}
```

Now if you want to add D to this rank at 2nd position

```
db.ranking.update({_id:"RANK"},{$push : {"ranks":{$each : ["D"],$position:1}}});
```

it would add D to index 1 which is 2nd position considering index starts at 0.

```
{
 _id : "RANK",
 "ranks" : ["A","D","B","C"]
}
```

But there is a catch, what if you want to change C position to 1st from 4th, you need to remove it from end and put it in the beginning, I am sure both operation can't be achieved in single update (didn't dig in the options much), so we can run two queries

```
db.ranking.update({_id:"RANK"},{$pull : {"ranks": "C"}});
db.ranking.update({_id:"RANK"},{$push : {"ranks":{$each : ["C"],$position:0}}});
```

Then it would be like 
{
 _id : "RANK",
 "ranks" : ["C","A","D","B"]
}

maintaining the rest of sequence.

Now you would probably want to store id instead of A,B,C etc. one document can be 16MB so basically this ranks array can store more than 1.3 million entries of id, if id is MongoDB ObjectId of 12 bytes each. if that is not enough, we still have option to have followup document(s) with further ranking.

**Approach 2**

you can also, instead of having rank as number, just have two field like followedBy and precededBy.

so your user document would look

```
{
 _id:"A"
 "followedBy":"B",
}
{
 _id:"B"
 "followedBy":"C",
 "precededBy":"A"
}
{
 _id:"c"
 "precededBy":"B",
}
```

if you want to add D at second position, then you need to change the current 2nd position and you need to insert the new One, so it would be change in only two document

```
{
 _id:"A"
 "followedBy":"B",
}
{
 _id:"B"
 "followedBy":"C",
 "precededBy":"D" //changed from A to D
}
{
 _id:"c"
 "precededBy":"B",
}
{
 _id:"D"
 "followedBy":"B",
 "precededBy":"A"
}
```

The downside of this approach is that you cannot sort in query based on the ranking until and unless you get all these in application and create a linkedlist sort of structure.

This approach just preserve the ranking with minimum DB changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rahul for your answer...i am planning to go with option 1...have some more data than a name...so have to perform an unwind lookup with the single document collection and master collection

Comment: Approach 1 would have been my choice too, It's fine to maintain an array of documents, but I would avoid to put any more nested arrays, as it would be difficult to perform operations.
In the same breath, I would also suggest to put a few fields as a document inside ranks array, rather than running aggregation with lookup if possible. Not only lookup is costly, aggregation itself has limits in terms or memory.

Comment: Hi Rahul...thanks for your persistent help...i assume you mean creating an array of documents inside the rank collection ?....

Comment: So...since i can have millions of documents inside the array in a single document.. is it a good optimization of db ?

Comment: Not only good, in my opinion that's the preferred approach, operation in a single document is atomic, so you cover transaction with update call. Document inside array is fine, I would not put large document, say maybe 3-4 required fields. Also you can use multi-key index on the array field to optimize it further.

Comment: I understand the hesitation of having a very large document, one side approach would be to maintain multiple document with sequence with 1000 documents in rank array of each. But I won't prefer it since it can get messy to maintain from application.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rahul...i was able to implement my feature using option 1...